# Using Unsafe.As to cast from marker interface to known generic type?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm commonly facing facing scenarios where I need to cache objects of a common generic interface, but with varying generic types.

Let's consider this very contrived example (obviously not precisely a real world use case):

```
// IInterface is effectively just use as a non-generic marker interface for...
interface IInterface
{ }

// ... This one here!
interface IInterface<T1, T2> : IInterface
{
    T1 DoSomething(T2 withB);
}

class TheCache
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IInterface, IInterface> _cache = new();

    public void Store<T1, T2>(IInterface<T1,T2> key, IInterface<T1, T2> value)
        => _cache[key] = value;

    private IInterface<T1, T2> Get<T1, T2>(IInterface<T1, T2> key)
    {
        // Can we use Unsafe.As safely here?
        return Unsafe.As<IInterface<T1, T2>>(_cache[key]);
    }
}
```

TheCache ensures type consistency; we know that each key and value in _cache are not just IInterface, but actually some generic manifestation of IInterface<,>. We also know that the generic types of key and value instance are the same.

Now in the Get function, we *know* that the the retrieved value will actualy be an IInterface<T1,T2>, but we still need to cast it. A "naive" way would simply be

```
    private IInterface<T1, T2> Get<T1, T2>(IInterface<T1, T2> key)
        => (IInterface<T1,T2>)_cache[key];
```

While that works perfectly well, I assume there's a (tiny) performance penalty to do a checked cast.

Gven we *know* the cast will succeed, is there any unchecked cast we could apply instead? Specifically,

1. Can we safely use Unsafe.As<IInterface<T1,T2>>() ? I'm not 100% firm on C# interface dispatch; while we know the result will be an instance of IInterface<T1,T2>(), I'm not sure if C# would generally need to do any translation when (safe) casting IInterface to IInterface<T1,T2>, which would not be present with an unsafe cast
2. Probably not, but just in case: Would the answer to this question changed if _cache was a Dictionary<object,object>, instead of Dictionary<IInterface, IInterface> ?

Comment: I'd love to know what you are doing that the performance difference is there. A checked cast is literally just a few instructions.